# Prevent chrome extension from running on page included in match specs

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am using a Chrome extension to extract data from pages created by en external website to which I have no access. As a part of the procedures, I want one such page (A) to open another one (B) from the same domain in a separate tab, but I do not want page B to run the extension script. Page B should be a "slave" to page A and be manipulated by the code running on page A. The problem is how to convey the message that page B should not run the script.

When page B is created, this can be solved by adding a fake hashtag "#dont_run_content_js" or the like to the url, which can be intercepted and interpreted by the script.

```
var url = window.location.href;
if(!url.includes("#dont_run_content_js")){//run main script}
```

But the user can of course navigate further in page B's new tab to another page within the matched domain, and then the message will be lost and the script executed upon loading of that next page.

On a page where every link is explicitly specified using an `href` attribute, those `href` values could be manipulated to include the message hashtag. But in this case, there are no `<a>` elements – linking occurs via an opaque mechanism that sends coded data from custom attributes to a remote javascript. So another option must be found to "bundle" a new page with a message to the script. Is that possible? Solutions involving jQuery are a bonus rather than an obstacle.

Comment: If you can switch to running content scripts programmatically via chrome.tabs.executeScript inside chrome.tabs.onUpdated or a webNavigation event listener, you can send a message from your main content script so your background script will set some global variable (and clear it after 100ms, for example) that will be checked by the main listener.

Comment: Thanks, sounds interesting. But you are using a lot of terms that I am unfamiliar with (running scripts programmatically, webNavigation event listener etc). Could you maybe point me in the direction of some documentation on this. Apologies for my ignorance.

Comment: You should use https://www.google.com or a similar site to search for terms. It usually takes just a few seconds to find the relevant documentation page.